# return json encode with array and single value

Tags: android, json

I want to return this back to my android emulator. This is a combination of jsonArray and jsonObject

```
[{"id":"11WAD01442","name":"Teng Kwang Wei"},{"id":"11WAD01443","name":"test 1"},{"id":"11WAD01444","name":"test 2"},{"id":"11WAD01445","name":"test 3"},{"status":true}]
```

What should I use to receive this json encode.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);
```

or

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the top object. In your case is an Array (of JSONObjects):

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);
 for (int i=0, len=jsonArray.length(); i<len; i++) try {
       JSONObject obj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
       String id=obj.getString("id");
       String name=obj.getString("name");
       .
       .
       Log.d("DUMP", "User "+i+": id="+id+", name="+name);

 } catch (JSONException e) {
       Log.d("DUMP", "Problem with user");
 }
```

Comment: At the end of my json_encode, i got a thing call "status", please scroll through my json_encode , it not an array, i just wondering can I do like that

Comment: Yes, it is an array that contains 4 objects. The thing is, the elements on an array in JSON can be different between each other! You have: [ {obj_user_1}  , {obj_user_2}  , {obj_user_3}  , {obj_status}  ]

Comment: Anyway, that encoding is not "parser friendly", the desirable thing would be a json object like this:   { status: { status_obj } , users: [ { user_1} , {user_2}, ...] } .  This way, is easier to parse from java, because you get all the users right away and don't need to study each object to decide if it is an user or a status .